# Google DataStudio Data Source: What does "Field editing in reports: OFF" do?

Tags: google-sheets-api, looker-studio

I can't find this documented anywhere. When editing a Sheets data source what does the large toggle for `Field Editing in Reports` do? When I turn this "ON" the data in my report changes significantly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the `Field Editing in Reports` allows users to re-aggregate and rename fields(dimension/metric) from within the Data Studio reporting UI. Previously, you would have to go and edit the data source to achieve the same result.

This is now done via the properties panel once you add a chart/table to a dashboard. After adding a field to your chart/table, click on the `Edit` button to the left of the field's name (see picture below). From here you can rename it and change the aggregation method if it is a metric.

[image: Data Studio Field Editing in Reports]